# Overlay adjusting the height to content

Tags: css

i'm trying to have the height auto adjust based on the content that's in the div.. i realize to do this, I shouldn't have a `height: xpx;`.

my popover is:

```
.popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 120px;
  z-index: 1010;
  display: none;
  max-width: 276px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

what's currently in the div of that popover is:

```
 span.details{
    display: block;
    font-family: Georgia,serif;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    color: #888;

}

span.status{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: -7px;
}

span.status strong{
    font-size:x-small; 
    vertical-align:top;
}

span.date{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
}

span.url{
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

what it looks like without the `height: 120px;`
http://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/2952f44fb396097037f8f5eaeabc52cd.png

what it looks like with the `height: 120px;`
http://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/614d383b7cba18a7f7a9bc017f53b9c4.png

any ideas here guys? i just want it to adjust to whatever is in the box!

Answer (score 0):

```
.popover {
    display:block;height:100%
}
```

try this